# Observing for changes in a List<>'s Count property?

Tags: c#, list, observablecollection

I'm looking to set up a listener on the `Count` property of a `List<>` object, i.e. when the count changes, execute some code.

What is the best way to set up an observable on an existing property of a built-in class like List?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't, basically. Use a class which was designed for that purpose from the start, such as [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx).

Comment: Fair enough. I was hoping I wouldn't have to modify my source code that much.